# How do you spy on an immer reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immer.js

Say this is my immer slice - how do i write a spy to on the updateValue reducer with Jest?? I would normally `import * as helperFunctions from "xyz"`, and spy on that, like `const exposeFormErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(helperFunctions, 'exposeEventToPartner');` to spy on the exposeEventToPartner function of the import called helperFunctions. But how do i do that with immer / how do I test an immer slice?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { initialState } from '../../../Data';
/**
 * This is going to be the largest piece of state, it is here where we hold all the required components for the app.
 */
export const components = createSlice({
  name: 'COMPONENTS',
  initialState: initialState.components,
  reducers: {
    updateValue(state, action) {
      const { payload } = action;
      const { componentId, value } = payload;
      state[`component_${componentId}`].component.input.value = value;
    },
  },
});

const { actions, reducer } = components;

export const { updateValue } = actions;

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to `import * as componentsReducer from '../../../src/Lib/redux/slices/components';` and then `const selectOptionSpy = jest.spyOn(componentsReducer, 'updateValue');`